# Pandas join and fill with last occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames:

DF1:

```
key | col1 | col2
 1     13     a
 1     15     b
 1     18     c
...   ...    ...
```

DF2:

```
key | col1
 1     14
 1     15
 1     19
...
```

I want to fill `DF2` with `col2` from `DF1` by using the keys: `["key", "col1"]`. If `DF1.col1` and `DF2.col1` don't have a match, I want to find the last occurrence in `DF1.col1` that is smaller then `DF2.col1`.

So the desired output would be:

DF2:

```
key | col1 | col2
 1     14     a # Not exact match, so it will take DF1.col1 = 13
 1     15     b
 1     19     c # Not exact match, so it will take DF1.col1 = 18
...   ...    ...
```

Using the traditional merge with pandas return None if there isn't a match:

```
result = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how="right", on=["key", "col1"])
```

result:

```
key | col1 | col2
 1     14    None
 1     15     b
 1     19    None
...   ...    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print (pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on="col1", by="key"))

   key  col1 col2
0    1    14    a
1    1    15    b
2    1    19    c
```

Note that this requires `col1` on both dfs to be sorted.

Comment: The output here is not the desired result but a replica of DF1

Comment: You are right, swap `df2` and `df1` and you should get your result.